# @Autowired Bean with @Async got null field

Tags: spring, spring-boot, null, autowired

The Springboot version is 2.6.13.

I have Class Data, it looks like this:

```
package com.example.asynctest;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@lombok.Data
@Async
public class Data {
    public class MyData{
        int age;
        String name = "";
    }

    private MyData myData = new MyData();
}
```

And when I try to get it autowired, the `myData` field is null.

```
package com.example.asynctest;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
@Async
class CmmandLine implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    private Data data;
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info(data.toString());
    }
}
```

The `data` field looks like this in IDEA:
[debug picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEDDn.png)

And when I remove the @Async annotation, the autowired `data.myData` is correct.I traced this by myself, and the bean was modified by `postProcessAfterInitialization` of `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.And I have added `@EnableAsync` on the entrypoint class.

So, why this happened? And how should I do to use @Async and @Autowired together?

Comment: I might be wrong but @Async should be above the method https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html

Comment: the doc says @Async can also be used at the type level, in which case all the type's methods are considered as asynchronous.

Comment: yes but maybe "data= new Data()" will be done asynchronous in that case, so try placing it above asyncMethod()

Comment: There has to be something else with your code. It is not possible the `data` field is null, as it is just a plain java assignment. Unless you are modifying this field in your code? You need to share more details. I've tried to reproduce your bug with no luck.

Comment: I reproduce it by a little case, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is not that the `data` object is not getting injected. In fact it does. To be absolutely sure you can change your code to have injection by constructor:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
@Async
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class CmmandLine implements CommandLineRunner{

    private final Data data;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info(data.toString());
    }
}
```

If the `data` object was not injected correctly, you would get an exception `Parameter 0 of constructor in industries.atende. Tester required a bean of type 'com.example.asynctest.Data' that could not be found.`. Moreover, even (theoretically) if you didn't get this exception, the `data.toString()` would yield a `NullPointerException`. Notice that neither of these exceptions occurs. So the code works (almost) correctly. You're looking for the error in the wrong place.

The real problem is that your `toString()` method in `Data` class returns `null`. The object itself is **not** null,but it appears to be null in IDEA debug, because the Intellij Idea also uses method `toString()` to picture the object for you. And the IDEA gets `null` from the `toString()` method.

So why the `toString()` returns null? Because you made it `@Async`. Every `@Async` method should return values wrapped by a class capable of dealing with asynchronous responses. For example you should always return `CompletableFuture<String>`, not just `String` if the method is `@Async`. Why? Because the method is run on another thread and, without this wrapper, you have no way of blocking it to get result (in another words: You have no way to "wait" for the result).

So my advice is to remove the `@Async` annotation from the top level (type), and use it only on methods that you really need to be async. Because otherwise you have no way of fixing the issue. The `toString()` is inherited from the `Object` class, so it cannot return `CompletableFuture<String>` - it has to return `String`. So making the method async, you would always end up with null instead of real value.

Comment: Nice analysis!!

Comment: So, you mean I should remove @Async from Data class, and add it to the method in Data?

Comment: Yes, definitely. :)

Comment: Another question is the myData feild in autowared data is actually null, when I use it, I got NullPointerException. Why is this happening?